# Ranorex - How to catch exception and return execution to the statement that threw Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automation, automated-tests, ranorex

Please help me with these 2 questions in Ranorex. I've been reading up but couldn't get it still.

1) How to catch exception and return execution to the statement that threw Exception ?

2) How can a method from Recording1.cs/Recording1.UserCode.cs be seen in Recording 2? By declaring private static, I don't see directly in the recorder table where i can select user code and function name in the drop down

3) If I want to define a common class for handling all the ElementNotFoundException occured in any test case in my test suite in Ranorex, how do I do that?
Can I be able to define/extend a class which all the test cases can be pointed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question1) you can use try..catch block as you use in C#.Similar you can try in Ranorex Scripts also.

Question 2) If you are using code module in Ranorex you can make an object of the class of which functions you want to call in another class.

Question 3)you can do it by creating a user defined exception class. refer the example on this link for User defined exception
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_exception_handling.htm